# Unicorn fcntl: Errno::EPERM: Operation not permitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, io, pipe, unicorn, fcntl

I've been running Rails application on Unicorn 5.5.5 and on certain environments it throws an exception which reads

```rb
bundler: failed to load command: unicorn (/usr/local/bundle/bin/unicorn)
Errno::EPERM: Operation not permitted
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/unicorn-5.5.0/lib/unicorn.rb:123:in `fcntl'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/unicorn-5.5.0/lib/unicorn.rb:123:in `block in pipe'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/unicorn-5.5.0/lib/unicorn.rb:116:in `each'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/unicorn-5.5.0/lib/unicorn.rb:116:in `pipe'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/unicorn-5.5.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:126:in `start'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/unicorn-5.5.0/bin/unicorn:128:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/bundle/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
  /usr/local/bundle/bin/unicorn:23:in `<top (required)>
```

I'd like to understand what `fcntl` does and why is this patch added. I don't really understand the internals around IO pipes and the code described here https://github.com/defunkt/unicorn/blob/master/lib/unicorn.rb#L115 and here https://bogomips.org/unicorn-public/20180820203038.25464-1-e@80x24.org/T/

Could someone explain why this is needed and what it actually does?

Comment: We have the same error, but only in environment production. In development all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

We have downgraded unicorn to **v5.4.1** and all is back to normal. I know that is not the solution but it helps to solve the problem for the moment.